# Table with linked sprite images

Tags: css, sprite

I'm trying to replace a table that has 6 linked icons with 6 linked sprite icons, but the table is just a blank. Here's a portion of the code - any ideas?

HTML:

```
<table><tr>
    <td><a href="https://twitter.com/french_lkl"><div id="icon-twitter" height="35" width="35"></div></a></td>
    <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/FrenchLanguage"><div id="icon-facebook" height="35" width="35"></div></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#icon-twitter, #icon-facebook, #icon-gplus, #icon-pinterest, #icon-rss, #icon-newsletter{
background: url(socialmedia.png) no-repeat;
}

#icon-twitter{
background-position: 0 0;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
}

#icon-facebook{
background-position: -36px 0;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Have you got a jsfiddle or an online example? By the way, it is more common to apply the background directly to the anchor.

Comment: It's in the upper right corner at https://www.lawlessfrench.com, to the right of the green printer icon.

I don't know what you mean by "apply background to anchor."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image doesn't exist.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: That's weird. In an earlier attempt, I had the image showing up over and over, so I know it's available.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
background: url('socialmedia.png') no-repeat;
```

Comment: Is the image located directly in your web directory or in a subfolder? Feels like your image path might be wrong

Comment: For others who might have the same issue: Yes, that was the problem, even though with a different version of the css, it was available, just not displaying correctly.